# cron at 15,55 and 35 every other hour

Tags: cron

first are these cron anyway similar and if so which ones are redundant?

```
a) 15,35,55 *   * * *
b) 15,35,55 */1 * * *
c) 15,35,55 0/1 * * *
```

What would be the cron to run at 35 and 15min/55min interchanged by an hour?

e.g

```
8am - 9am:   8:35am
9am - 10am:  9:15am and 9:55am
10am - 11am: 10:35am
11am - 12am: 11:15am and 11:55am
e.t.c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know what your cron is doing, then you can easily use [crontab-guru](https://crontab.guru/) to verify.

On your first question, yes the three examples are identical. The manual states the following :

> **`man 5 crontab`:** Step values can be used in conjunction with ranges.  Following a range with `/<number>` specifies skips of the
>   number's value through the range.  For example, `0-23/2` can be used
>   in the 'hours' field to specify command execution for every other hour
>   (the alternative in the V7 standard is
>   `0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22`).  Step values are also permitted
>   after an asterisk, so if specifying a job to be run every two hours,
>   you can use `*/2`.

See the following examples:

```
# Example of job definition:
# .-------------------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |        .----------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |        |      .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |        |      |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |        |      |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)
# |        |      |  |  |
# *        *      *  *  *   command to be executed
  15,35,55 *      *  *  *   command1
  15,35,55 */1    *  *  *   command2
  15,35,55 0/1    *  *  *   command3
  15,35,55 0-23/1 *  *  *   command4
```

So in the above example, `command[1-4]` will be executed at the same time, *every hour on minute 15, 35 and 55*

For your second question, it is best done this way :

```
# Example of job definition:
# .------------------------ minute (0 - 59)
# |      .----------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |      |      .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |      |      |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr .   
# |      |      |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)
# |      |      |  |  |
# *      *      *  *  *   command to be executed
  15    0/2     *  *  *   command1
  35,55 1/2     *  *  *   command1
  15    8/2     *  *  *   command2
  35,55 9/2     *  *  *   command2
  15    8-18/2  *  *  *   command3
  35,55 9-18/2  *  *  *   command3
```

Here, `command1` will execute on `{00,02,04,06,...,22}:15` and `{01,03,05,...,23}:{35,15}`, `command2` will execute on `{08,10,...,22}:15` and `{09,11,...,23}:{35,15}` and `command3` will execute on `{08,10,...,18}:15` and `{09,11,...,17}:{35,15}`.

Comment: so on second question, you mean I wouldn't have the schedule on one cron? I'm better off scheduling `command1` twice?

Comment: @legen---waitforit---dary yes, I just gave 3 options depending on your needs